# Couldn't handle android.intent.package_ADDED and REMOVED error while retrieving location using Fused Location API

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play-services

I am creating MainActivity class implementing LocationListener, GooglePlayServicesClient to get current location using FusedLocationApi. Its showing me some weird errors but that don't crash my app but functionality don't work. I am putting Log.i() to check whether control enters the overridden methods but it seems control dont enter in those methods. Below is the code and output. Please help

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener,android.view.View.OnClickListener   
  {
 private LocationClient mGetLocationLocationClient;
 private LocationRequest mGetLocationLocationRequest;
 private Location mGetLocationcurrentLocation;

 startBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    Log.i("in onStart", "yes..");
    mGetLocationLocationClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("in onLocationChanged", "Yes..");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("connectionFailed", "yes...shit");

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("in onConnected", "yes..here");
    /*
     * mGetLocationLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
     * mGetLocationLocationRequest
     * .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
     * mGetLocationLocationRequest.setInterval(50);
     * mGetLocationLocationClient
     * .requestLocationUpdates(mGetLocationLocationRequest, this);
     */
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("in onDisconnected", "yes..here");
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("in btnClick", "yes..");
    if (ok == GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this)) {
        Log.i("In googpleplayservice", "Available..");
        mGetLocationLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
        mGetLocationLocationClient.connect();
        // mGetLocationcurrentLocation =
        // mGetLocationLocationClient.getLastLocation();
    } else
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not..available",
        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mGetLocationLocationClient.disconnect();

}
```

**Here is my logcat output:**

```
02-23 04:36:06.351: E/Icing(806): Couldn't handle   android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED    intent due to initialization failure.
02-23 04:36:06.401: E/Icing(806): Couldn't handle  android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED intent due to initialization failure.
02-23 04:37:30.691: D/PackageBroadcastService(806): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED and uri=com.example.pedometer
02-23 04:37:31.001: E/Icing(806): Couldn't handle android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED intent due to initialization failure.
02-23 04:37:31.361: D/PackageBroadcastService(806): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED and uri=com.example.pedometer
02-23 04:37:31.711: D/PackageBroadcastService(806): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED and uri=com.example.pedometer
02-23 04:37:31.761: E/Icing(806): Couldn't handle android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED intent due to initialization failure.
02-23 04:37:31.781: I/PeopleContactsSync(806): CP2 sync disabled
02-23 04:37:32.341: I/PeopleContactsSync(806): CP2 sync disabled
02-23 04:37:32.411: E/Icing(806): Couldn't handle android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED intent due to initialization failure.
```

I am not getting why its showing problem with intent, I am never used it.
Please can anyone help me I read many posts but didnt found any answer.

Thanks in advance

My Manifest FIle

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pedometer"
    android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >

 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" 
    />
<!-- ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION FOR RETREIVING LOCATION THROUGH WIFI AND CELL TOWERS 
     ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION FOR RETREIVING LOCATION THROUGH GPS,WIFI,CELL TOWERS -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION"/>

  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
     >
     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.pedometer.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 

        >


        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.pedometer.GetLocation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        />
 </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: thanks donfuxx for suggesting, actually I am new to post on stack overflow

Comment: have added manifest David Wasser

Answer (score 1):

You have this in your manifest entry for your `MainActivity`:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
</intent-filter>
```

Why is this here? This is a broadcast Intent and has nothing to do with `Activity`. If you want to listen for this broadcast Intent you need to do it in a `BroadcastReceiver`.

Just remove this.